# Map data from array into Promises and execute code on Promise.all() not working

Tags: javascript, promise

I have an array like this

```
let array =[ {message:'hello'}, {message:'http://about.com'}, {message:'http://facebook.com'}]
```

I want to loop through it and at each item, I make a request to server to get open graph data, then save the fetched data back to array. Expected result

```
array =[ 
    {message:'hello'}, 
    {message: {
            url:'http://about.com', title:'about'
        }
    }, 
    {message:{
            url:'http://facebook.com', title:'facebook'
        }
    }
]
```

And I need to execute something else after the async fully complete. Below code is what I think it would be

```
let requests = array.map( (item) => {
    return new Promise( (resolve) => {
        if (item.message.is('link')) {
            axios.get(getOpenGraphOfThisLink + item.message)
            .then( result => {
                item.message =result.data
                // console.log(item.message)
                // outputs were
                //{url:'http://about.com', title:'about'}
                //{url:'http://facebook.com', title:'facebook'}
                resolve()
            })

        }
    })
})

Promise.all(requests).then( (array) => {
    // console.log (array)
    // nothing output here
})
```

The `promise.all()` won't run. `console.log(array)` does not output anything.

Comment: try to add return before axios   'return axios.get()...'

Comment: @ArtemKh: That wouldn't do anything.

Comment: Can you put a **runnable** [mcve] in the question (using Stack Snippets, the `<>` toolbar button), with something filling in for `axios.get`? Also, what do you see when you debug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see three main issues with that code:

1. Critically, you're only *sometimes* resolving the promise you create in the `map` callback; if `item.message.is('link')` is false, you never do anything to resolve. Thus, the `Promise.all` promise will never resolve.
2. You're accepting `array` as an argument to your `Promise.all` `then` callback, but it won't be one (or rather, not a useful one).
3. You're not handling the possibility of a failure from the `axios` call.

And if we resolve #2 by pre-filtering the array, then there's a fourth issue that you're creating a promise when you already have one to work with.

Instead:

```
let array = /*...*/;
let requests = array.filter(item => item.message.is('link'))
    .map(item => axios.get(getOpenGraphicOfThisLink + item.message)
        .then(result => {
            item.message = result.data;
            return result;
        })
    );

Promise.all(requests).then(
    () => {
        // Handle success here, using `array`
    },
    error => {
        // Handle error
    }
);
```

Note how reusing the `axios` promise automatically propagates the error up the chain (because we don't provide a second callback to `then` or a `catch` callback).

Example (doesn't demonstrate errors from `axios.get`, but...):

```js
// Apparently you add an "is" function to strings, so:
Object.defineProperty(String.prototype, "is", {
  value(type) {
    return type != "link" ? true :  this.startsWith("http://");
  }
});

// And something to stand in for axios.get
const axios = {
  get(url) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        resolve({data: "Data for " + url});
      }, 10);
    });
  }
};

// The code:
let array =[ {message:'hello'}, {message:'http://about.com'}, {message:'http://facebook.com'}]
let requests = array.filter(item => item.message.is('link'))
    .map(item => axios.get(/*getOpenGraphicOfThisLink + */item.message)
        .then(result => {
            item.message = result.data;
            return result;
        })
    );

Promise.all(requests).then(
    () => {
        // Handle success here, using `array`
        console.log(array);
    },
    error => {
        // Handle error
        console.log(error);
    }
);
```

Comment: @aw04: Heh, I'd twigged to that belatedly and was  just adding that. :-)

Comment: the  // Handle error part is for handling error of axios?

Comment: @angry_kiwi: Yes. The promise from `Promise.all` is resolved if all input promises resolve, or rejected if *any* input promise is rejected (and it doesn't wait for the others). If you instead want to handle those axios errors earlier, just do it as a second handler on the `then` inside the `map` callback (or as a `catch` there).

Comment: When I use redux thunk function dispatch({type   : constant.GET_POST,payload: array}) inside the // handle success. It will always dispatch the orginal array instead of the modified one. Any idea?

Comment: if I do settimeOut( ()=> dispatch(...), 4000) then it will dispatch the modified array. I thought when we code in // handle success section, everything is synchronous from there. I thought wrong?

Comment: @angry_kiwi The code in this answer will log the updated array, however... why modify the original array in map? It makes your code much less readable/easy to reason about (as you have noticed), and you could just as easily do res => console.log(res) as the success handler